# Different Permissions using decorators for each methods inside ModelViewset methods for "list", "create" , "retrieve", "update"

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, python-decorators, django-permissions

I want to add different permissions for different methods of ModelViewset class using decorator.

I tried:

```
class abcd(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    @permission_classes(IsAuthenticated,))
    def list(self, request, format=None):
        try:


    @permission_classes(CustomPermission,))
    def create(self, request, format=None):
        try:
```

But it isn't working.
I also tried using `@method_decorator`. That didn't worked either.

I know we can do in the following way:

```
def get_permissions(self):
    if self.action == 'create':
        return [IsAuthenticated(), ]        
    return super(abcd, self).get_permissions()
```

But I was wondering if we can achieve this using decorators for Django Rest Framework.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ModelViewSet` inherits `Mixin` classes and `GenericAPIView`. The methods `list` and `create` are from Mixins hence decorating with `permission_classes` won't work. Instead, you can try overriding `get_permissions` in `APIView`.

```
def get_permissions(self):
    if self.request.method == "GET":
        return [IsAuthenticated()]
    elif self.request.method == "POST":
        return [CustomPermission()]
    return [permission() for permission in self.permission_classes]
```

**Note: I am not sure whether above code works or not**

Comment: Should work, used something very similar with dict mapping though. Regarding of the preference one can also check for `self.action` against `list`, `create`, etc.

Comment: I knew about `def get_permissions(self):` . But didn't knew that it was inherited from Mixins and generics .

Answer (score 2):

a sample code is shown in official page.
so it might be better not using self.request.method but self.aciton property.

```
def get_permissions(self):
    """
    Instantiates and returns the list of permissions that this view requires.
    """
    if self.action == 'list':
        permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    else:
        permission_classes = [IsAdmin]
    return [permission() for permission in permission_classes]
```

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#introspecting-viewset-actions